# CakePHP and SQL Server 2008, Group By not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cakephp, group-by

Whenever I do a:

```
$this->Job->find('all', array(
        'group' => array('Job.some_field'),
        'recursive' => -1
    ));
```

I get a :

```
SQL Error: Column 'jobs.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

With MySQL it works fine but with SQL Server 2008 it seems that group by doesn't work anymore.
How do I fix this? Thanks in advance SQL gurus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is translated into something like this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Job
GROUP BY
        some_field
```

This is not a valid query according to `SQL` standards, however, it works in `MySQL` because of `MySQL`'s `GROUP BY` extensions.

You need to leave only grouped columns or aggregates in the `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT  some_field, COUNT(*)
FROM    Job
GROUP BY
        some_field
```

with something like this:

```
$this->Job->find('all', array(
        'fields' => array('Job.some_field', 'COUNT(*)'),
        'group' => array('Job.some_field'),
        'recursive' => -1
    ));
```

Comment: What if I'm using containable and have joins in my query?

Comment: @bakerjr: you need to make you query so that it translates into a valid `SQL`, that is no ungrouped *and* unaggregated columns in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: Got it thanks Quassnoi. Although what I really want is to get the distinct values of a field along with the joins that's why I'm using group in my find (plus containable).

You answered the question on this post though :)

Comment: @bakerjr: if you need `DISTINCT` values, you will most probably benefit from rewriting the joins as the `IN` conditions.

Comment: I guess I'm forced to write it as custom query in cake, do you agree? :/